# User ILogger<T> with Caliburn.Micro SimpleContainer

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, caliburn.micro

I have a .net-core 3 WPF application and I am trying to use Microsoft's `ILogger<T>` with Caliburn.Micro dependency injection system, but I do not how how to register in `SimpleContainer` a generic `ILogger`.

What I've done until now is to create an `ILoger` from a `LoggerFactory`:

```
var serilog = ConfigureLogger();
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory().AddSerilog(serilog);
ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("");


container.RegisterInstance(typeof(ILogger<>), nameof(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger), logger);

        private static Serilog.ILogger ConfigureLogger()
        {
            return new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Information()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}", theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate)
                .WriteTo.File("log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                .CreateLogger();
        }
```

This will not work if I will request in a view model an instance of `ILooger<MyType>` since the logger was created with an empty string as category name.

Should I use reflection to create an instance of a logger for every type in my application? This doesn't sound that good.

I know I can inject a `LoggerFactory` directly in DI, but this will imply to re-factor all class libraries to use it instead of a `ILogger` directly.

Comment: You can use a different DI container for that

Comment: That is a good idea. I will go ahead and do that.